# Coding Exercise: Watch the Pendulum

Tags: python, pendulum

> In physics, for a pendulum with length L and initial angle A, its horizontal >displacement X(T) at time T is given by the formula
>   X(T) = L × cos(A × cos(T × √9.8/L)) - L × cos(A)
>
> Write a program which takes two lines of input; the first line is L and the >second line is A. The output should be ten lines, giving the values of X(0), >X(1), X(2), ..., X(9). For example, if the first line of input is 53.1 and the >second line of input is 0.8, then the first line of output is 0.0 and the second >line of output is 53.1*cos(0.8*cos(1*√9.8/53.1)) - 53.1*cos(0.8) ~ 2.6689.

```
import math 
L = float(input())
A = float(input())
for T in range (0,9):
print(L*math.cos(A*math.cos(T*math.sqrt(9.8/L))-L*math.cos(A)))
```

i have written this and i cant understand what am i doing wrong ?

input :

```
53.1
0.8
```

my output:

```
3.545012155898153
7.383727226708044
17.92714440725987
31.889478979714276
44.23118522394127
51.212404291669216
53.079364553814806
52.890770379027806
52.999922313121566
```

expected answer:

```
0.0
2.6689070487226805
9.021742145820763
14.794542557581206
15.73774678328343
11.124903835610114
4.423693604072537
0.27377375601245213
1.295906539090336
6.863309996333497
```

Comment: ..should this be in Stack overflow or on another Stack site?

Comment: I believe you have a wrong bracket in there: change `L*math.cos(A*math.cos(T*math.sqrt(9.8/L))-L*math.cos(A))` to `L*math.cos(A*math.cos(T*math.sqrt(9.8/L))) - L*math.cos(A)`

Comment: @wohe1 i tried that, it did got me closer to the answer but still way off

Comment: You can find a solution for this online with some strategic googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bracket in the wrong place, change

```
L*math.cos(A*math.cos(T*math.sqrt(9.8/L))-L*math.cos(A))
```

to

```
L*math.cos(A*math.cos(T*math.sqrt(9.8/L)))-L*math.cos(A)
```

This gave the correct output on my pc

Edit:
also change `range(0,9)` to `range(10)`

Comment: thank you so much , it worked

Comment: I'm glad I could help, could you please accept this as an answer so the question doesn't seem to be unresolved?